# variables in subdomain in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a 2 php pages "download.php" and "windows.php"

the link of the both is

xyn.com/download.php?r=test

xyn.com/windows.php?r=test

Note : the two variable in the two pages are the same

I want to make the link of the pages like this

1 - download."variable".domain.com -> download.php?r=test 
2 - download."variable".domain.com/windows -> windows.php?r=test

the code I am using is :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.(.+?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    download.php?r=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.(.+?)\.domain\.com/windows$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    windows.php?r=%1 [L]
```

the first link is working fine :

download.variable.domain.com

but the second link is taking me to the first link :

download.variable.domain.com/windows

so any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \h/\h
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/download\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ download.php?r=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \h/windows\h
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/windows\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ windows.php?r=%1 [L]
```

all these subdomains should point to one document root

Answer (score 0):

Both conditions are on same `HTTP_HOST`, just add the `REQUEST_URI` as a condition.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/windows
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.(.+?)\.YourDomain\.net$
RewriteRule ^  http://YourDomain.net/download.php?r=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/windows
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.(.+?)\.YourDomain\.net$
RewriteRule ^  http://YourDomain.net/windows.php?r=%1 [L]
```

`http://download.babjhons.YourDomain.net/windows`

=>

`http://YourDomain.net/windows.php?r=babjhons`

Comment: is it working for `download."variable".domain.com -> download.php?r=test 2` ?

Comment: no it didn't work neither for download.php nor for windows.php

Comment: still doesn't work probably and download.variable.domain.com/windows is still taking me to the page download.php not windows.php

Comment: Testing with http://htaccess.mwl.be where the request url is `http://download.variable.domain.com/windows/testX`, The new url is `http://download.variable.domain.com/windows.php?r=windows/testX`

Comment: but the "r" variable should be the variable in the sub-domain not windows for example http://download.hossammagdy.domain.com/windows should referral to domain.com/windows.php?r=hosammagdy

Comment: i gave u a one and here is another one download.babjhons.domain.com/windows should referral to domain.com/windows.php?r=babjhons

Comment: yeah it worked fine but when i go to download.vairable.domain.com it redirect me to domain.com/download.php?r=variable and that's also happened in the second page

Comment: Ain't this what you want ?

Comment: yeah but i want the clean url to be the main url not the php one

that's mean when i go to domain.com/windows.php?r=variable it redirects me to the download.variable.domain.com/windows

Comment: This is another question that was not mentioned.

Comment: Maybe i couldn't lead my question so well .. but as you know by default the php links " uncleaned " is working well .. the problem is in the clean links .. so is there any way to this ?